# Why I can not pass a variable between controller functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope

I have this in a codeigniter controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public $idioma;

    public function index() {

        parent::__construct();

            // get the browser language.
        $this->idioma = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));

        $data["idioma"] = $this->idioma;
        $this->load->view('inicio', $data);

    }

    public function hello(){
        $data["idioma"] = $this->idioma;
        $this->load->hello('inicio', $data);
    }
}
```

Inicio view:

```
 <a href="test/hello">INICIO <?php echo $idioma ?></a>
```

hello view:

```
Hello <?php echo $idioma ?>
```

The inicio view works great, but when the hello view is loaded there's nothing displayed.
Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: `hello()` doesn't have `$this->idioma` set to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to set a class property automatically you would do it in the constructor, not in index(). index() does not run before other methods if they are called directly. In your case I assume you're calling hello via the url as test/hello

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public $idioma;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

            // get the browser language.
        $this->idioma = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));
    }

    public function index() {

        $data["idioma"] = $this->idioma;
        $this->load->view('inicio', $data);

    }

    public function hello(){
        $data["idioma"] = $this->idioma;
        $this->load->hello('inicio', $data);
    }
}
```